# Large sized images on website rendered on phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jpeg

I am working on a web application that stores and displays satellite images from a given location.

My problem is that these images are quite large (up to 20MB jpg-files) and this causes rendering problems on certain mobile devices.

On some android phones the image resolution is downgraded, while on some iOS devices the image won't even load. The iOS problem is maybe described [here](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-maximum-image-size/), but with no solution.

*Does someone have any experience with this kind of problem?*

I do apologize if my problem is to broad, but i am really just looking for some pointers or ideas.

I am developing in html/css with jquery/javascript and the server is hosted by cPanel with a Linux CentOS machine.

Regards Peder.

Comment: Are those images stored in your REST server?

Comment: The images are stored on the server. Not sure if it's a REST server though.

Comment: You usually don't load such a large image, you'll have to split it into smaller images and preferably load only the zoomed in part to make it load faster and save bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Any idea for scripts/frameworks that implements this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options:

1. Split those large images into smaller images and tile them (still downloads large amounts of data, but at least the client can do it in pieces)
2. Downgrade image resolution. That is, dynamically serve the quality of image that the client can actually handle.

Many map websites will use a combination of both. Being, they download a few high-quality segments for the area you look at closely and low-quality for all the areas you aren't looking at as closely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it makes sense. The combination solution is probably best. Do you know of any framework/scripts that solves this problem? I cannot be the first to need it.

Comment: Don't know if its what you need but this http://leafletjs.com/ is pretty popular. Or there seems to be a lot of related libraries you could investigate: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/javascript-libraries-for-interactive-maps/

Comment: Ok, so the idea is to make a map element, but somehow remove the default map and adding the image instead?

Comment: Yes... I've never really used these libraries for that purpose though so YMMV.